# Changing size of top label when using levelplot for array

Tags: r, arrays, lattice, levelplot

I've plottet some data from a 3-dimensional array using `levelplot()`.The 1st&2nd dimension names (`dimnames()`) are used as tick marks on the x- and y-axis, while the 3rd dimension name is displayed in a light-orange box on top of the graphs. How do I change the size of the text in this box?

Here is what I have so far:

```
> X<-array(runif(27,1,10),dim=c(3,3,3))
> dimnames(X)<-list(c("yesterday","today","tomorrow"),c(1:3),c("Elephant","Cat","Penguin"))
> levelplot(X)
```

I want Elephant, Cat and Penguin to be larger. I tried manipulating `scales`, `main.text.cex` and even looked into the properties of the plot to find my 3rd-dimension labels in a list called `condlevels$Var3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you faceted the plot, it's one of the paramters under strip, so do:

```
levelplot(X,par.strip.text=list(cex=2))
```

[image]